# Desktop doesn't show the files and nautilus don't launch

Tags: updates, nautilus

After updating the system from 16.04 to 16.10, desktop doesn't show the files, and nautilus launches but closes after 1 sec.
This is the error message from terminal:

```
(nautilus:6577): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: <broken file>:1:0: Failed to import: The resource at '/org/gnome/libgd/tagged-entry/default.css' does not exist
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process "net" (No such file or directory)
**
ERROR:nautilus-canvas-container.c:6032:finish_adding_new_icons: assertion failed: (!container->details->auto_layout)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I updated Ubuntu with these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install update-manager-core
```

Then I edited the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`:

from `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal`

And then `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: Before anything else make sure your system is full updated: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`, reboot and try again.

Comment: it didn't help..

Comment: Have you installed additional desktop environments or any other changes/tweaks before doing the release upgrade? If so please edit your question and add all relevant informations.

Comment: I've added instructions how I updated ubuntu, check it out.

Comment: That's **not** what I asked. How you did the release upgrade is pretty much irrelevant now. What you may or may not have done *before* is what matters.

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by this command:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/nautilus
```

Comment: This will delete the local configuration of Nautilus. I suggest to make a backup with `cp -a ~/.config/nautilus ~/.config/nautilus~`. Note: you don't need sudo, because ~ is your home directory and the files there should be owned by you.